# How to pass value using Intent between Activity in Android?

Tags: android

I want to pass the value of the position in one activity class to another...

My code is as follows:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(this, BucketItemActivity.class);
                newActivity1.putExtra("bucketno", position);
                startActivity(newActivity1);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(this, BucketItemActivity.class);
                newActivity2.putExtra("bucketno", position);
                startActivity(newActivity2);
                break;
    }
}
```

The activity class that will receive it..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bucket_item);
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bucketno");
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(value);
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

But i always get a null in the String value...

Please help.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bucket_item);
           Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = bundle.getString("bucketno");
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.textView1);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(value);
           
        }

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replace this,

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bucketno");
```

with

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("bucketno");
```

You are trying to pass int value but retrieving String Data. That's why you are getting the nullpointerException.

Comment: It should either be `int value` or `String value = String.valueOf(...);`. You're trying to store an `int` in a `String` with this bit of code. ;)

Comment: @Andro Selva u r right but he must get parseException or classcaste exception but he is getting nullpointer exception ?

Comment: One other thing I didn't think of before--`setText(value)` will fail on an `int` (in this context). `String.valueOf()` is the better way to go here.

Comment: or you can even you can use phil's solution if you need it to be String itself. Both will work good.

Answer (score 15):

You can use :

**In first activity ( MainActivity page )**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class); 
i.putExtra("YourValueKey", yourData.getText().toString());
```

then you can get it from your second activity by :
**In second activity ( SecondActivity page )**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String YourtransferredData = intent.getExtras().getString("YourValueKey");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String value = Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("bucketno"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) { 
    String data = intent.getExtras().getString("key").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**From the First Activity**

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BookPractionerAppoinment.class);
i.putExtra("prac","test");
startActivity(i);
```

**Getting values in Second ACT Activity**

```
String prac=getIntent().getStringExtra("prac);
```

**For Serialized objects:**

> Passing

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BookPractionerAppoinment.class);
 i.putExtra("prac",pract);
 startActivity(i);
```

> Getting

```
pract= (Payload) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("prac");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().get("key").toString();
```

`getIntent().getExtras()` will give you Boundle. `get()` method can be used to fetch the values.

Answer (score 0):

In addition who has different sittuation

```
  double userDMH = Util.getInstance(TakeInfoOne.this).calculateBMH(userGender, kg, talll, currentAge, activityy);
                        Intent intentTogeneral = new Intent(TakeInfoOne.this, TakeInfoTwo.class);
                        intentTogeneral.putExtra("user_current_age",userDMH );
                        startActivity(intentTogeneral);
```

If you put other primitives like double , boolean , int just dont forget to type correct format while geting the value in secont Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        double value =  extras.getDouble("user_current_age");
        txt_metabolism.setText(""+value);
    }
```

Here with  `extras.getDouble()` type your concerned value type like

```
extras.getInt("user_current_age");
extras.getBoolean("user_current_age");
 extras.getString("user_current_age");
```