# How to send and retrive values through calling Intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send calling contact number and contact id through Intent and retrive using BroadCast reciver.Is it possible, if possible then how?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017720/how-to-pass-value-using-intent-between-activity-in-android

Answer (score 1):

After search and R&D I realise we can't do this thing.
I solve this problem using Globle class which contain contactNumber and contactId.
So initialize this static field and use when broadcast reciver hit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set extra values to your intent from the activity/fragment like :

```
myIntent.putExtra( "theKey" , theValue);
```

And retrieve them into the called activity into the `onCreate` like:

```
Intent i = getActivity().getIntent(); 
Bundle b =  i.getExtras();
Boolean myValue = b.getBoolean("theKey",false );
```